# XCode: Call action in main view from modal view

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am trying to call an action (changeMainNumber) in a main view controller from a modal view controller. The action should change the UILabel mainNumber to 2. In ViewController.h, I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *mainNumber;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *mainNumber;

-(IBAction)changeMainNumber;
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mainNumber;

- (IBAction)changeMainNumber:(id)sender {
mainNumber.text = @"2";
}
```

The next view controller is the modal view controller.
ModalViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface ModalViewController : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)callChangeMainNumber:(id)sender;
```

and ModalViewController.m:

```
#import "ModalViewController.h"

@implementation ModalViewController

- (IBAction)callChangeMainNumber {
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[viewController changeMainNumber];
}
```

With this setup the app keeps crashing when callChangeMainNumber is called and I can't figure out what is wrong. Any help you can provide is appreciated!

Comment: Crashing? What's the message? Where does it crash? Do you know you are creating a new ViewController inside callChangeMainNumber and changing it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The app is crashing when the callChangeMainNumber action is run (round rect button). I do not know exactly what to do, so what would be the correct way to call changeMainNumber with callChangeMainNumber?

Comment: What do you mean when the callChangeMainNumber is run? Which line? The correct way is to pass the ViewController object to the ModalViewController object so the last one can send the changeMainNumber message to the first object. Got it?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I'm a little new at this, so how would I go about passing the ViewController object to ModalViewController?

Comment: Depends, you could set a property on ModalViewController called mainController and do modalViewController.mainController = self; if you initialize modalViewController on the ViewController class.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted from your ModalViewController is not referencing your ViewController. You are creating a new one in your code. The best solution to your problem would be to make your ViewController a delegate to the ModalViewController.

So in your ModalViewController.h file you should have this code above your @implementation.

```
@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate
    - (void)shouldChangeMainNumber;
@end
```

Then in your @implementation of the header have:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign)IBOutlet id <ModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Now in the .m file where you have your IBAction method, tell the delegate that you want it to change the main number.

```
- (IBAction)callChangeMainNumber {
    [self.delegate shouldChangeMainNumber];
}
```

Then in your ViewController.m file you need to set yourself as the delegate of the ModalViewController, usually in viewDidLoad is a good place to put it. So create a property in your header for the ModalViewController first and synthesize it, then add this to viewDidLoad.

```
self.modalViewController.delegate = self;
```

and finally you need to implement the delegate method in your .m file somewhere

```
- (void)shouldChangeMainNumber {
    mainNumber.text = @"2";
}
```